# обьект не прыгает

Tags: javascript, html, css

дино не прыгает при нажатий на пробел но в ид приходит класс jump

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>dino</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/dino.png" type="image/png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dino.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="prjt">
        <div id="dino"></div>
        <div id="cactus"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="dino.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

.prjt{
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#dino{
    background-image: url("img/dino.png");
    background-size: 40px 50px;
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 150px;
    animation: walk 0.5s infinite linear;
}
#cactus{
    background-image: url("img/cazus.png");
    background-size: 20px 50px;
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 100px;
    left: 580px;
    animation: line 3s infinite linear;
}
.jump{
    animation: jump 1s  linear;
}
@keyframes walk{
    0%{
        background-image: url(img/dino2.png);
        background-size: 40px 50px;
    }
    30%{
        background-image: url(img/dino2.png);
        background-size: 40px 50px;

    }
    50%{
        background-image: url(img/dino3.png);
        background-size: 40px 50px;
    }
    100%{
        background-image: url(img/dino.png);
        background-size: 40px 50px;

    }
}
@keyframes jump{
    0%{
        top: 150px;
    }
    30%{
        top: 80px;
    }
    50%{
        top: 20px;
    }
    80%{
        top: 80px;
    }
    100%{
        top: 150px;
    }
}
@keyframes line{
    0%{
        left: 580px;
    }
    100% {
        left: -20px;
    }
}

    const dino = document.getElementById("dino");
const cactus = document.getElementById("cactus");

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    jump();
});

function jump(){
    dino.classList.add("jump") //добавить функцию jump в dino
}
```

Comment: `.jump { animation: jump 1s linear !important; }`

Comment: спасибо помогло